# Peculiar git performance issues in a shared nfs directory.

Tags: filesystems, cache, git, vagrant

I have vagrant vm running ubuntu on a native macbook pro. I have a shared nfs folder where a git project is checked out. There are issues with git performance between the VM and the native filesystem.
For Example when I execute git status on the native mac it is very fast. Right after, if I switch to the VM and execute git status in the same shared directory it's very slow. then switching back to the mac and executing git status makes it slow. Here are some stats:

1. on mac
   `time git status` ->
   `git status  0.05s user 0.07s system 151% cpu 0.082 total`
2. on vm:
   `time git status` ->
   `git status  0.67s user 0.77s system 17% cpu 8.455 total`
3. back on mac:
   `git status  0.39s user 0.63s system 36% cpu 2.785 total`

So it looks like executing git status on the mac and then on ubuntu is affecting the performance. Is git invalidating it's cache when I switch between the systems?